# Pressing both mouse buttons not working correctly

Tags: java, swing

i have to check if i pressed left, right or both buttons on my mouse, here is a sample code:

```
package sandbox;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Sandbox extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sandbox s = new Sandbox();
    s.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Sandbox() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Frame");
    setLayout(null);
    JButton but = new JButton("click me");
    but.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 50);
    but.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) | SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
            System.out.println("both");
        else if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
            System.out.println("left");
        else if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
            System.out.println("right");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
    add(but);
    }

}
```

i have to make it using SwingUtilities, but there is a problem if i press left or right single button it will print "both", not "left" or "right", if i used MouseEvent class it was working properly but i need it with SwingUtilities class if it's possible, thanks.

EDIT: using MouseEvent class it's working right:

```
if(e.getModifiersEx() == (MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK | MouseEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK))
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't check using OR (`|`) but use AND (`&` or better the short cut version `&&`) instead:

```
if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
  ...
```

**Update**:

For checking if both buttons are pressed, `SwingUtilities` doesn't seem to be the right tool. The `isXxxxMouseButton(...)` methods do the same as you do, they check the button masks, but use different masks which seem not be set when both buttons are pressed.

As an example, `isRightMouseButton()` is implemented as follows:

```
public static boolean isRightMouseButton(MouseEvent anEvent) {
    return ((anEvent.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
}
```

As you can see, the implementation isn't that complext, so you might be better off to just do the mask check yourself.

Comment: It's not working, in this case it's "impossible" to press both buttons at the same time

Comment: @CharlieHarper well, it seems as if `SwingUtilities` is not the right tool for the job then. IIRC you'd have to check the event for `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK | BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK` but `SwingUtilities` uses `BUTTON1_MASK` and `BUTTON3_MASK`, which are not recommended according to the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1):

mouse listene event on button

```
but.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
```

mouse listener event on fame.

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
```

Please check with `'||' not '|'`, don't use the && because it is not possible  to press both buttons at the same time

```
if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) || SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
```

You will get result

```
both
left
both
left
both
right
```

Comment: Did you try the code? because it's not working, same problem, and i think it's irrelevant if i add MouseListener to button or to the Frame.

Comment: @Charlie Harper Yeah, same code your code , just but.addMouseListener to this.addMouseListener, and it works

Comment: Man it's not working to mee, i can't believe it's working to you, my code: http://pastebin.com/j1GmhbAx //still can't believe what can be different if i add mouselistener to button or to frame i think it's not important.. for me it's working the same.

Comment: If you need mouse event on button then add it on button , if you need mouse event on frame then you add it on frame, it should work at your side, may other problem at your side

Comment: where are you clicking if you add it on button then click on button left , if you added it on frame then click on frame

Comment: Yes that's i was writing about, it's irrelevant if im clicking on button or on frame, the code is working the same for both cases

Comment: If you made changes then Please recompile your code again ,